# Difference beetween http://www.app.in and http://app.in

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-chrome, dns, cross-domain-policy

What is the difference between http://www.app.com and http://app.com

and how it affects to cross-domain policy of Ajax

I mean i added ajax request in app

```
                 $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://app.in/getToken",
                      contentType: "text/html",
                      success: function(msg) {
                               alert(msg);
                          }
                    });
```

it works in chrome but not in firefox

Whats the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Same Origin Policy chapter of Michal Zalewski's Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2). www.example.com is a different domain than example.com under same-origin policy.

As Deanna points out, scripts *can* communicate with each other through iframes or separate windows if the subdomain sets its `document.location` to the higher domain. However, setting `document.location` has no effect on XMLHttpRequests; the domain and subdomain cannot send XMLHttpRequests directly to each other.

Answer (score 1):

They are different sites.
IIRC, there is a tag you can add to each site saying "this is the same site" for XSS but I can't remember detaisl or how standard it was.
As for a solution, use relative URLs.